# Cannot find module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have folowing directory structure:

```
--app
  -- test
    -- server.js
  -- app.js
```

I try to call function in app.js which exports from server.js, i do:

```
var server = require("test/server");
```

But get error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'test/server'
```

How can i include it correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path must be relative to the file you are currently in.

Use `var server = require("./test/server");`

Comment: @0xAX You should select this as the correct answer if it worked and there's nothing else to add.