# Node.js cannot find module

Tags: node.js, module

I have 3 `js` files:

- app.js
- server.js
- utils.js

There is `express` server starts in `server.js`. `app.js` call server start from `server.js`. `app.js` is in root directory and there also is a src directory with `server.js` and `utils.js`. When I'm trying:

```
var utils = require('utils');
```

In `server.js` I get error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'utils'

Why? `utils.js` and `server.js` are in the same directory.

Thank you.

Comment: require("./utils") !!!

Comment: Great :) Thank you. Post answer i'll mark it

Comment: Are you kidding me -_-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990500/cannot-find-module-in-node-js/16990563#16990563

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to write:

```
require("./utils")
```

Otherwise it will try to load utils.js from the node_modules directory.